# Discord Bot returns "DiscordAPIError[50035]"

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

This is my **ticket_system.js** file:

```js
const {
    Client,
    MessageEmbed,
    MessageActionRow,
    MessageButton,
    Modal,
    TextInputComponent,
  } = require("discord.js");
  const settings = require("./settings");
  
  /**
   *
   * @param {Client} client
   */
  module.exports = async (client) => {
    // code
  
    client.on("interactionCreate", async (interaction) => {
      if (interaction.isCommand()) {
        if (interaction.commandName == "ping") {
          return interaction.reply({
            content: `> Pong :: ${client.ws.ping}`,
          });
        } else if (interaction.commandName == "setup") {
          // code
          let ticketChannel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.get(
            settings.ticketChannel
          );
          if (!ticketChannel) return;
  
          let embed = new MessageEmbed()
            .setColor("BLURPLE")
            .setTitle(`Ticket System`)
            .setDescription(`> click on button to create ticket`);
  
          let btnrow = new MessageActionRow().addComponents([
            new MessageButton()
              .setCustomId("ticket_create")
              .setStyle("SECONDARY")
              .setLabel(`Create Ticket`)
              .setEmoji("️"),
          ]);
          await ticketChannel.send({
            embeds: [embed],
            components: [btnrow],
          });
  
          interaction.reply({
            content: `Ticket System Setup in ${ticketChannel}`,
          });
        }
      }
  
      if (interaction.isButton()) {
        if (interaction.customId == "ticket_create") {
          const ticket_modal = new Modal()
            .setTitle("Ticket System")
            .setCustomId("ticket_modal");
  
          const user_name = new TextInputComponent()
            .setCustomId("ticket_username")
            .setLabel(`What is Your Name`.substring(0, 45))
            .setMinLength(3)
            .setMaxLength(50)
            .setRequired(true)
            .setStyle("SHORT");
  
          const user_reason = new TextInputComponent()
            .setCustomId("ticket_reason")
            .setLabel(`Why are you creating ticket ?`.substring(0, 45))
            .setMinLength(3)
            .setMaxLength(100)
            .setRequired(true)
            .setStyle("PARAGRAPH");
  
          const row_username = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(user_name);
          const row_user_reason = new MessageActionRow().addComponents(
            user_reason
          );
          ticket_modal.addComponents(row_username, row_user_reason);
  
          await interaction.showModal(ticket_modal);
        } else if (interaction.customId == "ticket_delete") {
          let ticketname = `ticket-${interaction.user.id}`;
          let oldChannel = interaction.guild.channels.cache.find(
            (ch) => ch.name == ticketname
          );
          if (!oldChannel) return;
          interaction.reply({
            content: `> Your ticket deleting in few seconds`,
          });
          setTimeout(() => {
            oldChannel.delete().catch((e) => {});
          }, 5000);
        }
      }
  
      if (interaction.isModalSubmit()) {
        const ticket_username =
          interaction.fields.getTextInputValue("ticket_username");
        const ticket_user_reason =
          interaction.fields.getTextInputValue("ticket_reason");
  
        let ticketname = `ticket-${interaction.user.id}`;
        await interaction.guild.channels
          .create(ticketname, {
            type: "GUILD_TEXT",
            topic: `ticket of ${interaction.user.tag}`,
            parent: settings.ticketCategory || interaction.channel.parentId,
            permissionOverwrites: [
              {
                id: interaction.guildId,
                deny: ["VIEW_CHANNEL", "SEND_MESSAGES"],
              },
              {
                id: interaction.user.id,
                allow: [
                  "VIEW_CHANNEL",
                  "SEND_MESSAGES",
                  "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY",
                  "EMBED_LINKS",
                  "ATTACH_FILES",
                  "MANAGE_CHANNELS",
                  "ADD_REACTIONS",
                  "USE_APPLICATION_COMMANDS",
                ],
              },
              {
                id: client.user.id,
                allow: ["ADMINISTRATOR", "MANAGE_CHANNELS"],
              },
            ],
          })
          .then(async (ch) => {
            let embed = new MessageEmbed()
              .setColor("BLURPLE")
              .setTitle(`Ticket of ${interaction.user.username}`)
              .addFields([
                {
                  name: `Name`,
                  value: `> ${ticket_username}`,
                },
                {
                  name: `Reason`,
                  value: `> ${ticket_user_reason}`,
                },
              ]);
  
            let btnrow = new MessageActionRow().addComponents([
              new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId(`ticket_delete`)
                .setStyle("DANGER")
                .setLabel(`Delete`),
            ]);
            ch.send({
              content: `${interaction.member} || ${settings.ticketRoles.map(
                (r) => `<@&${r}>`
              )}`,
              embeds: [embed],
              components: [btnrow],
            });
            interaction.reply({
              content: `> Your Ticket Created in ${ch}`,
              ephemeral: true,
            });
          })
          .catch((e) => {
            interaction.reply({
              content: `Error \n \`${e.message}\``,
              ephemeral: true,
            });
          });
      }
    });
  };
```

And this is my **settings.js:**file:

```js
module.exports = {
  token: process.env.TOKEN,
  ticketChannel: "166757627673791795",
  ticketRoles: ["54654646472135798721"],
  ticketCategory: "1113229624508420206",
  guildId: "841213248978975646531",
};
```

I was just following a tutorial and got this weird error. I literally followed the tutorial exactly how they told me, but in the video, they don't get this error and I do. I don't have a lot of knowledge about Discord.js so please help me out on this one.

> There was an error: DiscordAPIError[50035]: Invalid Form Body
> name[BASE_TYPE_REQUIRED]: This field is required

Comment: Can we get the full error? What line is supposedly throwing this error?

Answer (score 0):

Your code has a lot of errors that might cause this problem. These are the error I can now find. Correct me if you find anything else or want more help. I have recreated your code here:

### NOTE:

***Also you code seems to be generated with the help of an AI! ChatGPT or AI Tecnology in general are temporarly banned form StackOverFlow! See [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned?cb=1)!***

```js
const { ChannelType, PermissionFlagsBits, EmbedBuilder, ActionRowBuilder } = require("discord.js");

await interaction.guild.channels
          .create({ //Channel Name does not go here!
            name: ticketname,
            type: ChannelType.GuildText, //"GUILD_TEXT" Is outdated in Discord.JS V.14
            topic: `ticket of ${interaction.user.tag}`,
            parent: settings.ticketCategory || interaction.channel.parentId,
            permissionOverwrites: [
              {
                id: interaction.guildId,
                deny: [PermissionFlagsBits.ViewChannel,
                       PermissionFlagsBits.SendMessages,
                ], //"VIEW_CHANNEL" & "SEND_MESSAGES" are outdated in Discord.JS V.14
              },
              {
                id: interaction.user.id,
                allow: [
                  "VIEW_CHANNEL",
                  "SEND_MESSAGES",
                  "READ_MESSAGE_HISTORY",
                  "EMBED_LINKS",
                  "ATTACH_FILES",
                  "MANAGE_CHANNELS",
                  "ADD_REACTIONS",
                  "USE_APPLICATION_COMMANDS",
                ], //Do the same here (As above).
              },
              {
                id: client.user.id,
                allow: ["ADMINISTRATOR", "MANAGE_CHANNELS"],
              }, //Do the same here (As above).
            ],
          })
          .then(async (ch) => {
            let embed = new EmbedBuilder()
              .setColor("Blurple") //Don't use capitals
              .setTitle(`Ticket of ${interaction.user.username}`)
              .addFields([
                {
                  name: `Name`,
                  value: `> ${ticket_username}`,
                },
                {
                  name: `Reason`,
                  value: `> ${ticket_user_reason}`,
                },
              ]);
  
            let btnrow = new ActionRowBuilder().addComponents([
              new MessageButton()
                .setCustomId(`ticket_delete`)
                .setStyle("Danger") //Don't use capitals
                .setLabel(`Delete`),
            ]);
```

*PS: This works only in Discord.JS V.14. The tutorial you might watching might be outdated or work in an older version of Discord.JS.